# Display all data in db and use for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I have a checkbox which will re-enable all input textboxes in a row if checked. The current state is I can only  do it on the first row.

This is my code:

```
@foreach($kucings as $cat)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
         <input type="hidden" name="" value="">
         <input type="checkbox" id="name" name="name" value="{{$cat->id}}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         {{$cat->name}}
      </th>
      <td><input type="number" id="age" value="" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="weight" value="" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="height" value="" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Below is my javascript:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('name').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('age').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('weight').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('height').disabled = !this.checked;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: your problem is two fold. your onchange event is only hooked with one row because you're using ID, just use classes if you want it applied to all. second, if you try to submit the form with two rows of age, weight, and height enabled, only the last row will be saved. so in your name attribute, you need to set it as `<input name="input[0][name]"` and next row `input[1][name]` and the rest in order for PHP to properly process the complete input

Comment: Its too complicated for me. Can u show me the solution ?
Its been near a week I tried this

Comment: im guessing your target would be to save all 3 rows if those rows are enabled, right? but my statement still remains, use classes instead of IDs, and use an array name group so that you can save multiple rows that are enabled

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It takes time to apply the script through the loop and now its work. Now I'm struggling the submit data to database part

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`. You can have dynamic `id` like this and add event listeners for each of them.

```
  @foreach($kucings as $key => $cat)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
         <input type="hidden" name="" value="">
         <input type="checkbox" id="name-{{$key}}" name="name" value="{{$cat->id}}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         {{$cat->name}}
      </th>
      <td><input type="number" id="age-{{$key}}" value="" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="weight-{{$key}}" value="" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="height-{{$key}}" value="" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach

<script>
  let catCount = {{count($kucings)}};
  for (let i = 0; i < catCount.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('name-'+i).onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('age-'+i).disabled = !this.checked;
      document.getElementById('weight-'+i).disabled = !this.checked;
      document.getElementById('height-'+i).disabled = !this.checked;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.. But this code not working for me. I'm using a Laravel 8 for web developing

Comment: @wanprogrammer Can you tell me which syntax is not supported?

Comment: There's no error display and interface is shown. But when checked the checkbox it is not functioning for all textbox.. my previous code can run on one row.